# How to store data in a float type? (append)

Tags: python, numpy, append

How to store data in a float type (append) Python?

```
data=                    #data is a float64
 [ 335  -2.2827743]
 [ 340   4.5311280]
 [ 358   0.4698628]
 [ 367   3.8023018]
 [ 388   2.9782774]

result=[]

i in range(0,4):
    if data[i][0]<360:    
    result.append(data[i])
```

The result I want:

```
result=
 [ 335  -2.2827743]
 [ 340   4.5311280]
 [ 358   0.4698628]
```

Comment: What is `data`. A list?

Comment: data is a float64

Comment: That is just plain bad syntax.

Comment: I'm new in Python

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. At the very least, try and run the code you are providing.

Comment: Why `range(0, 4)`? Why don't you want to process the last element of `data`? Why not use `for element in data:`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare that directly like:

#### Code:

```
result = data[data[:, 0] < 360]
```

#### Test Data

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([
    [335, -2.2827743],
    [340,  4.5311280],
    [358,  0.4698628],
    [367,  3.8023018],
    [388,  2.9782774],
])

result = data[data[:, 0] < 360]
print(result)
```

#### Results:

```
[[ 335.          -2.2827743]
 [ 340.           4.531128 ]
 [ 358.           0.4698628]]
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I also use an interval? Like, between 300 and 350?

Comment: I tried this but finish with the message: TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Comment: `data[(300 < data[:, 0]) & (data[:, 0] < 350)]`

Comment: Sorry to bother, now the result is a bool (True, True, True, False,False)

Comment: Put the conditional into `data[...]`, see above.  This conditional, as you noted builds a Boolean vector.  That vector can then be used to select elements.

Comment: Thank you for the patience! It helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you wanted:

```
data=[
 [ 335,  -2.2827743],
 [ 340,   4.5311280],
 [ 358,   0.4698628],
 [ 367,   3.8023018],
 [ 388,   2.9782774]]

result=[]

for i in range(0,4):
    if data[i][0]<360:    
        result.append(data[i])
```